# Bloomberg equity option volatility data

Tags: volatility, programming, bloomberg

Using the Bloomberg open API, I am trying to program a C++ script that is able to download option volatility data from Bloomberg. I currently do not have access to Bloomberg, but in the coming week I will be able to access a Bloomberg terminal to try out my script.

In which field are the individual option volatilities saved? I know that the last price field would be PX_LAST or LAST_PRICE, but have no idea in which field / format the option volatility would be accessible.

Comment: The easiest way to find a field is to go to a ticker you are interested in on a terminal, say `SPY US 02/20/15 P200 Equity <Go>` and then type `FLDS VOLATILITY`: you will see a page with a list of fields related to volatility.

Comment: Well as I said, I currently do not have access to a Bloomberg terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For real time you could use `IVOL_MID_RT` (or ASK or BID) and for historical data `IVOL_MID` (or ASK or BID).

Note that the vol is derived from the mid price using a B&S model (PDE for american options).

Comment: Thanks! Do you also happen to know the fields so I can obtain the data from all the volatility surface?

Comment: I don't think there is one field for that. I suspect you would have to get the volatility for several options (various strikes/maturity) and draw the surface from that data. HELP HELP on Bloomberg may know better.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll send a message to Bloomberg help then when I can use it.